# SwiftUI State updates in Xcode 11 Playground

Tags: ios, swiftui, grand-central-dispatch, swift-playground, xcode11

I have not been able to find anything through the standard Google search, but is there any reason why the `ContentView` is not updating through the `ObservableObject`? Feel like I am missing something but I am not quite sure what.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

let start = Date()
let seconds = 10.0 * 60.0

func timeRemaining(minutes: Int, seconds: Int) -> String {
    return "\(minutes) minutes \(seconds) seconds"
}

class ViewData : ObservableObject {
    @Published var timeRemaining: String = "Loading..."
}

// View

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewData: ViewData = ViewData()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewData.timeRemaining)
        }
    }
}


let contentView = ContentView()
let viewData = contentView.viewData
let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)


// Timer

let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()
timer.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: .seconds(1))
timer.setEventHandler {
    let diff = -start.timeIntervalSinceNow
    let remaining = seconds - diff
    let mins = Int(remaining / 60.0)
    let secs = Int(remaining) % 60
    let timeRemaning = timeRemaining(minutes: mins, seconds: secs)
    viewData.timeRemaining = timeRemaning
    print(timeRemaning)
}
timer.resume()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
    timer.cancel()
    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(contentView)
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that GCD based timer works on own queue, so here is the fix - view model have to be updated on main, UI, queue as below

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    viewData.timeRemaining = timeRemaning
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main utility of GCD timers over standard timers is that they can run on a background queue. Like Asperi said, you can dispatch the updates to the main queue if your GCD timer isn’t using the main queue, itself.

But, you might as well just schedule your GCD timer on the main queue from the get go, and then you don’t have to manually dispatch to the main queue at all:

```
let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: .main)
```

---

But, if you’re going to run this on the main thread, you could just use a `Timer`, or, in SwiftUI projects, you might prefer Combine’s [`TimerPublisher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/timerpublisher):

```
import Combine

...

var timer: AnyCancellable? = nil
timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
    .sink { _ in
        let remaining = start.addingTimeInterval(seconds).timeIntervalSince(Date())

        guard remaining >= 0 else {
            viewData.timeRemaining = "done!"
            timer?.cancel()
            return
        }

        let mins = Int(remaining / 60.0)
        let secs = Int(remaining) % 60

        viewData.timeRemaining = timeRemaining(minutes: mins, seconds: secs)
}
```

When you incorporate your timer within your SwiftUI code (rather than a global like here), it’s nice to stay within the Combine `Publisher` paradigm.

I also think it’s probably cleaner to cancel the timer when it expires in the timer handler, rather than doing a separate `asyncAfter`.

---

Unrelated, but you might consider using `DateComponentsFormatter` in your `timeRemaining` function, e.g.:

```
let formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    formatter.unitsStyle = .full
    return formatter
}()

func timeRemaining(_ timeInterval: TimeInterval) -> String {
    formatter.string(from: timeInterval) ?? "Error"
}
```

Then,

- It gets you out of the business of calculating minutes and seconds yourself;
- The string will be localized; and
- It will ensure grammatically correct wording; e.g. when there are 61 seconds left and the existing routine will report a grammatically incorrect “1 minutes, 1 seconds”.

`DateComponentsFormatter` gets you out of the weeds of handling these sorts of edge cases, where you want singular instead of plural or languages other than English.